# How to return list of values selected in dropdown using flask and html

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have four dropdowns and I trying to return a list of all the options selected back. I am using html with flask. I have a button placed named start. I need that on the click of start button the list of all the 4 options selected in the dropdown should be returned. 
I am very new to Flask. This is the first time I am working with it, so please help me.[image]

The html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale =1.0">
    <title>Select Options</title>
   <style>
    body {
        background: url("F:/Meethi Folder/COLLEGE/COMPETITIONS/Sidh Competition/nmims_logo.png");
        background-position:515px 330px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:15%;
         }

    h2 {
     color: black;
       }

    .wrapper{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .button{
        position:absolute;
        left:570px;
        background-color:#A9A9A9;
        font-size: 30px;
        top:35%;
    }   

    form{
        display:inline-block
    }

    .ex
    {
    margin:auto;
    width:90%;
    padding:40px;
    border:outset;
    }

    select
     {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:16px;
    }
    .ey
    {
     display:inline-block;
    padding:40px;
     } 

    .gap{
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    }

   </style>
  </head>

<body>

<div class = "ex">
<form method="post">
<h2> Choose The Programme:</h2>
      <select name="val">
        <option value="None">Select Programme</option>
        <option value="BTech">BTech</option>
    <option value="BTech Integrated">BTech Integrated</option>
        <option value="MTech">MTech</option>
        <option value="MBATech">MBATech</option>" . $options . "
      </select>
</form>

<form class = "ey">
<h2> Choose The Course:</h2>
      <select>
        <option value="None">Select Course</option>
        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
    <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
        <option value="DS">Data Science</option>
    <option value="Electrical">Electrical</option>
    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    <option value="CS">Chemical</option>
    <option value="CS">Mechatronics</option>
        <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
    <option value="Mech">Mechanical</option> " . $options . "
      </select>
</form>

<form class="ey">
<h2> Choose The Year:</h2>
      <select>
        <option value="None">Select Year</option>
        <option value="First Year">First Year</option>
        <option value="Second Year">Second Year</option>
        <option value="Third Year">Third Year</option>
    <option value="Fourth Year">Fourth Year</option>
    <option value="Fifth Year">Fifth Year</option>
    <option value="Sixth Year">Sixth Year</option>
      </select>
</form>

<form class = "ey">
<h2> Choose The Hour:</h2>
      <select>
        <option value="None">Select Time Slot</option>
        <option value="8:00 am">8:00 am</option>
        <option value="9:00 am">9:00 am</option>
        <option value="10:00 am">10:00 am</option>
    <option value="11:00 am">11:00 am</option>
    <option value="12:00 pm">12:00 pm</option>
    <option value="1:00 pm">1:00 pm</option>
    <option value="2:00 pm">2:00 pm</option>
    <option value="3:00 pm">3:00 pm</option>
    <option value="4:00 pm">4:00 pm</option>
    <option value="5:00 pm">5:00 pm</option>
      </select>
</form>

<br><br>

<div class = "wrapper">
<button class = "button" onclick=click()>Start</button>
</div>


</div>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the code. What is `$options` after the options in the select tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post the data to your flask server using either plain forms, or JS.

This will be your HTML:

```
<form class = "ey" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('submitForm') }}"> <!-- note action -->
    <select name="select1"> <!-- note the name -->
        <option value="None">Select Course</option>
        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
        <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
        <option value="DS">Data Science</option>
        <option value="Electrical">Electrical</option>
        <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
        <option value="Chem">Chemical</option>
        <option value="ME">Mechatronics</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And there should be something similar to this on flask:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, \
     request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home', methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/submit-form', methods = ['POST'])
def submitForm():
    selectValue = request.form.get('select1')
    return(str(selectValue))
```

**Update #1**

Change your python code to:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template,request,redirect,url_for,Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

@app.route('/home',methods = ['GET'])
def home():
  return render_template('form2.html')

@app.route("/hello", methods = ['POST'])
def hello():
    select = request.form.get('val')
    return select


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: It says Internal Server Error Occurred

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: It is not giving an error anywhere, when I compile it and the screen loads on local host, instead of dropdowns it says that Internal Server Error

Comment: Hi so, in the line where request.form.get() is used it gives an error saying Working outside of request context.  This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for information about how to avoid this problem.

Comment: It's not compiling only, but throws this error in the line where I call request.form.get('select1')

Comment: @KopalSharma can you please share your python code ? in text form not in image

Comment: from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template,request,redirect,url_for,Flask
from FlaskWebProject3 import app

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home',methods = ['GET'])
def home():
   return render_template('UI2.html')
   

@app.route("/hello", methods = ['POST'])  
def hello(): 
    select = request.form.get('val')
    return select

Comment: <body>

<div class = "ex">
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('hello')}}" >
<h2> Choose The Programme:</h2>
      <select name="val"> 
        <option value="None">Select Programme</option>
        <option value="BTech">BTech</option>
     <option value="BTech Integrated">BTech Integrated</option>
        <option value="MTech">MTech</option>
        <option value="MBATech">MBATech</option>" . $options . "
      </select>


<div class = "wrapper">
<button class = "button" type ="submit">Start</button>
</div>

</form>


</div>

</body>

Comment: @KopalSharma I've edited my answer. check out update #1. I've tested it